# Ember JS - Reference view inside linkTo

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an Ember JS confusion. First of all I have to admit I'm a bit of an Ember newbie so apologies if this is obvious.

I have the following template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="threadListItem">
    {{#linkTo show thread.receiverLogin}}
        <h4>{{thread.receiver.login}}</h4>
        <span>{{view.prettyTime}}</span>
    {{/linkTo}}
</script>
```

There's basically a linkTo helper with some elements inside of it.

The weird thing is the {{view.prettyTime}} doesn't display anything when it's inside the linkTo.

However, if I move the span outside the linkTo it finds the view variable ok and it works.

Is there anyway to get access to the view object inside the linkTo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Christopher is correct that you can access the prettyTime property with:

```
{{view.parentView.prettyTime}}
```

Since you're new to ember, it's maybe worth mentioning that in most cases it is best to avoid accessing properties of the view. Instead, consider adding a `prettyTime` property to your controller. The controller will be the default context for sub-views like the one created by the linkTo helper, so you'll be able to access it with just

```
{{prettyTime}}
```

Answer (score 0):

linkTo creates its own view, so the view you want to get access to is the parentView of view.

```
{{view.parentView.prettyTime}}
```

Comment: Since you're new to ember, it's maybe worth mentioning that in most cases it is best to avoid accessing properties of the view. instead, consider adding a `prettyTime` property to your controller. The controller will be the default context for sub-views like the one created by the linkTo helper, so you'll be able to access it with just `{{prettyTime}}`.

Comment: Michael could you add this as a second answer. It's certainly a more 'complete and correct' answer, as mine merely addresses the immediate issue of why view.prettyTime is empty.